# 'Column 'userimage' cannot be null' Error only on larger image files

Tags: php, html

I'm having trouble with an image upload form, with most images it works just fine but with larger image files I get a `Column 'userimage' cannot be null` error.

I have changed the following values in my `php.ini` file;

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
memory_limit
```

I'm using a prepared statement(I've just included a small section here);

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (user, area, userimage, socialurl) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){

        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $user, $area, $userimage, $socialurl);
```

I've tried searching but I can't find a similar problem.

My code, I've edited out some that isn't relevant to make the question shorter;

```
<?php
    $error = "";
    $dangererror = "";
    $successmsg = "";
    require("config/connect.php");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){      

      if(empty($_POST['user'])) {
        $error .= "User is required<br>";
      } 

      if(empty($_POST['area'])) {
        $error .= "Location is required<br>";
      }      

      if(isset($_FILES["userimage"]) && $_FILES["userimage"]["error"] == 0){
        $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
        echo $_FILES["userimage"]["name"];
        $userimage = $_FILES["userimage"]["name"];
        echo $userimage;
        $filetype = $_FILES["userimage"]["type"];
        $targetDir = "uploads/";
        $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $userimage;

        $targetThumbFilePath = "uploads/thumbs/";

        if(!file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["userimage"]["name"])){


          // Verify file extension
          $ext = pathinfo(strtolower($userimage), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

          if(array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) {

            $maxsize = 5000000; 

            if($_FILES['userimage']['size'] < $maxsize) {

              if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userimage"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
                $successmsg .= "<div class='alert alert-success'>Image - " . $userimage . " - Uploaded Successfully!</div>";

                $upload = 'uploads/' . $_FILES["userimage"]["name"];
                list ($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize ($upload);

                //switches content-type and calls the imagecreatefrom... function
     <!------------- cut ------->

                //switches content-type and saves thumbnail
     <!------------- cut ------->

              }

            } else {
              echo "test";
              $error .= "File Exceeds 5mb Limit<br>";
              }

          } else {
              $error .= "Invalid File Format<br>";
            } 

        } else { 
            $error .= "The Filename " . $_FILES["userimage"]["name"] . " already exists - please rename your picture before uploading<br>";
          }

      }

      if($_POST['socialpage'] != ""){

        //switches content-type and saves thumbnail
      <!------------- cut ------->

      }

      if($error) {
        $dangererror = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
        $dangererror .= $error;
        $dangererror .= "</div>";
      } 
        else {
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (user, area, userimage, socialurl) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){

            // Set parameters
            $user = $_REQUEST['user'];
            $area = $_REQUEST['area'];           

            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $user, $area, $userimage, $socialurl);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $successmsg .= "<div class='alert alert-success'>Image Added Successfully!</div>";
            } else{
                echo "ERROR: Could not execute query: $sql. " . $conn->error;
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . $conn->error;
        }

        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();

        // Close connection
        $conn->close();
      }
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when I set the following options in the `php.ini` file;

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
memory_limit
```

I set the values too high as;

```
If the upload_max_filesize is larger than post_max_size, you must increase post_max_size so that it is bigger than upload_max_size.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have no `else` clause on this `if`:

```
if(isset($_FILES["userimage"]) && $_FILES["userimage"]["error"] == 0){
```

As a result, if `$_FILES['userimage']` is unset, or if there is an error (i.e. `$_FILES["userimage"]["error"] != 0`), your `$error` variable remains an empty string and so you attempt to make an `INSERT` even though you haven't set the value of `$userimage`. You need to add an `else` clause something like this:

```
elseif (isset($_FILES['userimage']) {
  // must have been an error uploading i.e. $_FILES["userimage"]["error"] != 0
  $error .= "Error uploading file, error code = " . $_FILES["userimage"]["error"];
}
else {
  // no uploaded file!
  $error .= "No file uploaded!";
}
```

Comment: This is a good addition to my script. I solved the issue with incorrect `php.ini` values but your answer was very helpful. thanks